# covariance matrix

Tags: r, geor

I was wondering if any one could explain to me how the geoR package calculates the covariance function? I mean how you would do it by hand?

```
library(geoR)
#suppose I have the following coordinates
X = c(60,30,20,40)
Y = c(50,20,50,50)
my_coordinates = cbind(X,Y)
print(my_coordinates)

#computing covariance
my_cov= varcov.spatial(my_coordinates,cov.model="exp", cov.pars=c(0.2,25))
print(my_cov)
```

And you get:

```
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.20000000 0.03664442 0.04037930 0.08986579
[2,] 0.03664442 0.20000000 0.05645288 0.05645288
[3,] 0.04037930 0.05645288 0.20000000 0.08986579
[4,] 0.08986579 0.05645288 0.08986579 0.20000000
```

However, one might want to do it in Matlab as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the source? You can do so just by typing the function name at the R command prompt. The function includes several variations according to the supplied args, but the individual code paths don't look particularly obscure.

Comment: As stated below, your distance matrix `h` does not correspond to your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to find out how a package or function does something is to look at the source code. This is one of the awesome things about open source projects, you can do this.

try typing `varcov.spatial` or searching through the unpacked package tar ball for the function definition

To calculate the covariance (which is dependant on the distance between points), you need to calculate

- the distance between your points (you really only need the lower triangle, as it will be symmetric
- The value of the covariance function at each distance
- form the full symmetric variance covariance matrix from these calculated covariances.

The covariance functions are defined in `?cov.spatial`. You can call `cov.spatial` to calculate these in `R` (exactly what `geoR::varcov.spatial` does)

Comment: @ToNoY -- your example distances aren't from your example data. The lower triange of your distance matrix is `as.vector(dist(my_coordinates))` which gives `[1] 42.42641 40.00000 20.00000 31.62278 31.62278 20.00000`

Comment: @ToNoY -- the default is [euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) -- see `?dist`. I don't know where you got your numbers from.